# how to run mpi commands from Jupyter ipython kernel

Tags: ipython, mpi, jupyter

I am trying to run the mpiexec command from the cell in Jupyter, firstly i am not sure what to write, should i write :

```
!mpiexec -np 4 mynotebook.ipynb
```

Secondly, when i run the above mpi command it runs fine but does not give me any output.

Here is what i did :

I installed ipyparallel and started ipcluster from terminal(Mac OS X).

I ran the command:

```
ipcluster start --profile=mpi -n 4
```

The servers started succcessfully but it does not show the profile "mpi" in iPython clusters in jupyter homepage.

[image: jupyter Homepage]

Have i done all the steps right?

I love Jupyter and i would like to run mpi commands from there. TIA.